# Closing process and question edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, vote-to-close

Questions that do not fit the scope of the respective sites get voted to close, if 5 people voted to close it (and unless 3 voted against), the question get closed. Once it it closed, the OP can edit his/her question, and that bring the question on the reopen queue.

This is all fine on a site like SO, or here on meta, where there are many users and finding 5-7 reviewers does not take too much time.

On a less frequented site, the review process of a question may take some time. It can be several minutes, to several hours. The OP, noting that there are some VTC is incited to edit his/her question immediately without waiting for the question to be completely closed.

But then the earlier people who voted to close have a vote still there, which does not correspond to the edited question. When there are several successive edits, we might have the case that the review process is made with each reviewer having voted for a different version of the question.

Wouldn't it make sense to ask reviewers to re-evaluate their vote after a question got edited, and before it actually get closed? Or at least authorize them to change their vote?

Comment: Certainly is. If someone can close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin you can do it yourself by clicking the blue button

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I can do it when someone voted to close as duplicate, right, not  before... or can I?

Comment: You can also vote to close or flag (depends on reputation) as duplicate, and the banner will appear.